# How do I mount a power distribution block inside a NEMA 1 pull box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

I want to splice 6/3 wires into multiple 6/3(or 8/3) wires at my home.

I read answers [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/200914/splicing-6-3-wire-to-multiple-8-3-wires-or-even-other-6-3-wires-inside-a-junct) and decided to use power distribution blocks. This is what I bought ([Mersen MPDB62163](https://www.zoro.com/mersen-power-dstribution-block-cu-mini-85a-3p-4-mpdb62163/i/G9038473/)).

I never mounted a PDB before, is it compatible with pull boxes like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/WIEGMANN-N1-WEIGMANN-6-in-W-x-6-in-H-x-4-in-D-Carbon-Steel-Gray-Screw-Cover-Wall-Mount-Box-1-Pack-SC060604RC/100584755) one? What kind of mounting method can I use?
Can I directly drill holes at the box, and directly mount the PDB to the stud?
Are there types of boxes that are compatible with the PDB?

Answer (score 6):

### This is easy

The good news is that in a NEMA 1 (indoor) application, we don't have to worry about water, so we can simply use sheet metal screws of the appropriate size to screw the PDB to the back of the box, as it has mounting holes in its base.  Do mind your bending space when you're selecting the size of the pull box, though!

### Oh. Ground.

Grounding the box, fortunately, doesn't require a PDB pole.  For the wires you're using, a fat wirenut or Wago splice and a bare or green 10AWG pigtail to the 10-32 grounding screw in the back of the pull box will work just fine, which means you don't have to worry about finding a grounding bar you can mount with a 10-32 screw.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! For sheet metal screws, do I need to pre drill holes? I see some boxes are made of steel. I've never worked with (large sized) sheet metal screws on steel. Do I need to get any specialized tool besides a regular drill?

Comment: @Yang it depends on your sheet metal screw -- some screws require predrilling, but others don't.  And no, you won't need anything besides a drill/driver for this

Comment: @Yang there are self-drilling screws (common brand is Tek) that make their own perfect sized hole in sheet metal. Installing one of them with a standard drill is a piece of cake. You will know you have the right screws because they have a little drill bit at the start before the threads.